# Inflate and render a UI view by a downloaded xml string

Tags: android, android-layout, xml-parsing, layout-inflater, android-xmlpullparser

I was interested in downloading the xml layout for UI views from a server and inflate that as an xml string.
What I see in the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) though is:

> Therefore, it is not currently possible to use LayoutInflater with an
>   XmlPullParser over a plain XML file at runtime; it only works with an
>   XmlPullParser **returned from a compiled resource (R.something file.)**

I don't really understand the highlighted part (my emphasis).
If I have some "dummy" xml file to get the `XmlPullParser` could I inflate my xml string?

And in general if this is impossible what alternatives are there?
I mean besides that does not require a huge learning curve like react native

Answer (score 0):

You can’t inflate view hierarchy from plain XML files, because of the unusual implementation of `LayoutInflater`. According to [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/LayoutInflater.java#362), the following `inflate` methods won’t work with a simple instance of `XmlPullParser`.

```
    View inflate(XmlPullParser parser, ViewGroup root)
    View inflate(XmlPullParser parser, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)
```

The implementation requires that the first argument `parser` is an instance of [`class XmlBlock.Parser`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/res/XmlBlock.java#79). The class implements [`interface XmlResourceParser`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/XmlResourceParser), and the interface extends three interfaces:

- [`XmlPullParser`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser)
- [`AttributeSet`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/AttributeSet)
- [`AutoCloseable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/AutoCloseable)

Therefore, simple `XmlPullParser` is not enough for the `inflate` methods. The APIs should be:

```
    View inflate(XmlBlock.Parser parser, ViewGroup root)
    View inflate(XmlBlock.Parser parser, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)
```